# Uploading an Android app for Beta - Package Error

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload an App for the Beta version from the Google Play Developer Console.

But when I tried to upload the APK, which I've achieved through:

- **Build** > **Generate Signed APK**

It returned me an error message saying the Package name shouldn't start with com.example or such common words.

---

So I googled how to change the Package name, and I've found out I had to **right click** on the name of the **package** (on 'example') and then **refactor** it to fianlly **rename** it into another word, which I chose to be '**FET**'.

I re-built the APK, loaded on the Dev Console, but **it keeps saying that it can't start with** `com.example`.

What's wrong?

Comment: chech your package in `build.gradle` and `manifest`

Comment: I've already checked the Manifest (package="com.FET.leonardo.scurcola") but instead on that build.gradle it says: applicationId "com.example.leonardo.scurcola". Is that line only I've to change? @AkshayBhat

Comment: yes, you have to change in gradle as well. After changing clean the project and rebuild.

Comment: It works. Please, feel free to post an answer I can accept @AkshayBhat

Comment: I've added it as answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change package in gradle as well. After changing clean the project and rebuild.